# Git check custom rules

Tags: git

Hello fellow programmers!

Recently, I started learning Git, and pretty quickly discovered the amazing diff --check option, that doesn't let those nasty stray whitespaces get in the commit. But those are ot the only things you'd like to exclude from the commit - there often are various debug statements in the code. So, what I'd like to know is whether there is any way of configuring git diff --check to watch after that?

Maybe I should use the similar functionality of Vim / emacs, and stop looking for options where they do not belong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may wish to investigate the [Pre-commit hook](http://book.git-scm.com/5_git_hooks.html) which is the usual place to check for those sorts of errors. By using the pre-commit hook, Git will automatically check all commits without you having to remember to run `diff --check`.